# How to using android's camera surfaceView and overlaying view in Fragment?

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, android-fragmentactivity

In my application I want ot use surfaceview to show the PreView from the camera, and show some tips on the view. I needn't to storage the image.I want to use FragmentActivity to achieve that. I am a novice, can you give me any tutorial? Thank you~

Answer (score 0):

Try this xml. It contain 2 containers one for camera preview and other for hints whose background needs to be invisible to show the underlying camera preview inside FrameLayout which enables one container to be above the other.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/camera_preview_linear_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview_surface_view"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </SurfaceView>    
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/camera_takepicture_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Take picture">
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/camera_preview_hints"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:orientation="vertical"> 
    <!-- Your hint goes here-->
</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```